# DateDiff not functioning as expected, unable to troubleshoot

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to set up a query to pull records where the date the record was entered into the database, [AssignmentDate], is compared against today's date, via Now(), to determine whether the record is older than a value selected by the user, e.g. 30 days, 60 days, etc.

Here's the code I have to set a String, SelectionVariables, to the SQL I want:

```
SelectionVariables = "WHERE (DateDiff('d', [AssignmentDate], Now())>'" & _
                        CaseAge.Value & _
                        "');"
```

Case.Value is the user-selected value from a drop-down.  I'm absolutely baffled by the result I get, with Case.Value = 30: the query pulls two records that are dated 6/1/2015 and 5/1/2015, as expected.  It does not pull the two records dated 7/15/2015 and 8/1/2015, as expected.  It does not pull the record dated 1/1/2015, and for the life of me I cannot diagnose why it isn't getting that one.  I haven't found any information indicating that DateDiff has some sort of range that I am exceeding, so I'm left baffled.

Your magical expertise is most appreciated.

Comment: Is there no other filtering criteria?  A `JOIN` perhaps?  When you exclude the `WHERE` and include the `DATEDIFF()` as a field in your `SELECT` list does it return the expected value for that record?

Comment: What happens if you change your code to this? `SelectionVariables = "WHERE DateDiff('d', [AssignmentDate], Now())>" & CaseAge.Value & ";"`

Answer (score 1):

HansUp's comment fixed the issue:

> What happens if you change your code to this? SelectionVariables = "WHERE >DateDiff('d', [AssignmentDate], Now())>" & CaseAge.Value & ";" –  HansUp 24 mins >ago

It appears that the extra parentheses around my original expression were the issue:

```
(DateDiff('d', [AssignmentDate], Now())>'" & CaseAge.Value & '"');
```

Not certain why those parentheses cause the expression to evaluate incorrectly, but so it is.

Comment: I removed the single quotes before and after `CaseAge.Value` so the db engine would evaluate it as a number instead of a string.